# Unable to Fetch a Webpage

Tags: c#, .net, http, get

I am newer than "egg" in .NET and C# and wanted to test whether I am getting HTTP Response (GET) or not. Since working behind the firewall, I am not sure whether the problem lies in Code or Security.

Code which is copied from http://www.csharp-station.com/howto/httpwebfetch.aspx

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;


/// <summary>
/// Fetches a Web Page
/// </summary>
class WebFetch
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // used to build entire input
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // used on each read operation
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

        // prepare the web page we will be asking for
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create("http://www.mayosoftware.com");

        // execute the request
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
            request.GetResponse();

        // we will read data via the response stream
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        string tempString = null;
        int count = 0;

        do
        {
            // fill the buffer with data
            count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            // make sure we read some data
            if (count != 0)
            {
                // translate from bytes to ASCII text
                tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                // continue building the string
                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

        // print out page source
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Error:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: 'WebApplication6._Default' is not allowed here
>   because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"
>   MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Line 2:
>   CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication6._Default" %>
>   Line 3:

Any hint, about how to solve this problem. Very noob so will appreciate the "baby steps" very much.

Comment: Wait are you building a console app or a web page?

Comment: @MikeChristensen just want to get the XML or JSON of the content of web page

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be that of a console app, an application that compiles to an .EXE and can be run from the command line.

However, your error message is that of an ASP.NET application; an application designed to run within the process of a web server.

Your question was unclear as to which type of application you're *actually* trying to build.  If it's the former, then all you should need to do is compile your app with Visual Studio or `csc.exe` as an executable (which can be done by right clicking on the project, selecting *Properties* and setting the Output type to *Executable*), and run it.  If you're having trouble there, I'd suggest just starting over again and creating a new project in Visual Studio, this time selecting "Console App".

If you're trying to build a web page, then you have a few problems.  First, in your page directive (the `<%@ Page ... %>` thing), you'll need to set the `Inherits` attribute to the name of your class.  For example, `WebFetch`.  Next, this class needs to derive from `System.Web.UI.Page`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Fetches a Web Page
/// </summary>
public class WebFetch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  //...
}
```

If you do this, you should probably override the `Render()` method and write directly to the output stream:

```
/// <summary>
/// Fetches a Web Page
/// </summary>
public class WebFetch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   {
      // All your code here

      writer.Write(sb.ToString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you're using the wrong project type here. The error message you are seeing is from ASP.NET. The code you're attempting to use is for a Console Application.

The simplest fix is to start a new project, and make sure to choose the correct project type (Console Application).

If you actually want this to be an ASP.NET website, you need to make sure to include a page that derives from System.Web.UI.Page.

Comment: Thanks @Curtis. I got the following error while entering it through Console Application "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required"

Comment: That means your code worked, but either the web server itself or (far more likely) your firewall is returning an HTTP 407 error.